# jquery simple modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use jquery with simple modal plugin. When in modal user select the cell of table i need to do information about this cell. Size of table and info about cell take different amounts of space on the screen. I want to change size of modal window, can i do that without closing modal window?
part of function which called when user click table cell:

```
// temp element for display data about record in table
var tmp = $("#temp")[0];
// table invisible
$("#tableells")[0].style.display="none";
// do temp element visible
tmp.style.display="";
// fill temp element with data of record (name is par of function)
tmp.innerHTML = name;
// here i want to change size of modal window
```

Comment: you need to post some code for us to help you. i'm sure it's possible, but how to do so exactly requires a bit of code from you

Comment: Well, you're using jQuery, but you're not utilizing it's potential...any reason to not use the [jQuery functions](http://api.jquery.com/) for what you're doing?

Comment: i need to change attributes value using jquery functions? why? standart mechanism for that very simple and convenient, why i must do that i do not understand can you try to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple different options.

1) To let SimpleModal determine the size based on the new content, call:

```
$.modal.setContainerDimensions();
```

2) To tell SimpleModal what dimensions you want to use:

```
$.modal.update(height, width);
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: $.modal.setContainerDimensions();
not change size of modal window, i also try to set autoResize: True in .modal() calls $.modal.update(height, width) works.